# Why can't I su to root via ssh?

Tags: debian, ssh, virtual-machine, root, su

I've set up two VMs with exactly the same image (debian-11.3.0-amd64-netinst - headless).

The only things I touched on these machines are:

- Root password
- Sysad password
- Installed sudo command
- Changed IP addresses
- Changed SSH Ports
- Installed UFW, changed SSH Port and activated OpenSSH & WWW Full

On the machine I created first, everything works properly: I can SSH into it with the `sysad` user and then use `su root` followed by root password to gain root access (ssh root login disabled by default).

On the machine I created second (with the exact same image), I can SSH into it with the `sysad` user but `su root` throws me an "Authentication failure".

`journalctl` tells me basically the same thing:

```
pam_unix(su:auth): authentication failure...
```

I checked groups and uids for both systems and the configurations are exactly the same. Also, I am 100% sure of the password. Su + root password works when doing it on the machine directly (via the hypervisor). I also entered the password multiple times by hand, even tried to check for a false char-set by typing the password in the username field to see it in clear text.

Does anyone have an idea about what I am missing here?

Comment: Note that `su root` is pointless, it's exactly the same as `su` unless you have set up your system to have some other user as UID 0.

Comment: "Authentication failure" usually means the wrong password. Are you 100% sure you are giving the correct password for the root account?

Comment: Thanks for your replay terdon, the error shows also when doing su though.. Also i am 100% sure of the password. Su + root password works when doing it on the machine directly (via the hypervisor). I also entered the password multiple times by hand, even tried to check for a false char-set by typing the password in the username field to see it in clear text..

Comment: Do you have securetty or other tty based restrictions?

Answer (score 4):

You mention you specifically installed `sudo`, but then you explain you use `su` to get root access. The two commands are not the same, although they achieve the same end result.

Either but not both:

```
sudo -s    # Ask for root access, usually authenticate with the caller's password
su         # Ask for root access, authenticate with the target's (root) password
```

Another possibility is that your source username is in the necessary group to be able to use one of these commands, but you need to log out and in again for it to be activated.

Check group memberships not just in `/etc/group` but also with the `id` command.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I only wrote about sudo because I wanted to clarify what I did on the machines. I checked group memberships and they are exactly the same for both machines. (Otherwise I wouldn't be able to do su on the machine itself via the hypervisor. It must have something to do with SSH i believe..

Answer (score -1):

in addition to what was mentioned,

see `/etc/sudoers` by doing `visudo` and (at least in RHEL 7 with what I am familiar with) there is a `%wheel` line that requires users be a member of the **wheel** group in order to successfully `su` to root.  I'm not sure at the moment going from memory how much this affects use of the `sudo` command preceding some other command.

You may also consider editing `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` and uncommenting and make `PermitRootLogin YES` that will facilitate access by allowing you to SSH between your VM's directly as root rather until you figure out your `su` and `sudo` setup.

xxx  Generally nothing under `/etc/pam.d` if that is all default and unmodified should affect what you are doing (at least for what I am familiar with under RHEL, I assume the same is so with Debian) xxx

**update:** this is the default `/etc/pam.d/su` from RHEL 7.9

```
#%PAM-1.0
auth            sufficient      pam_rootok.so
# Uncomment the following line to implicitly trust users in the "wheel" group.
#auth           sufficient      pam_wheel.so trust use_uid
# Uncomment the following line to require a user to be in the "wheel" group.
auth            required        pam_wheel.so use_uid

auth            substack        system-auth
auth            include         postlogin
account         sufficient      pam_succeed_if.so uid = 0 use_uid quiet
account         include         system-auth
password        include         system-auth
session         include         system-auth
session         include         postlogin
session         optional        pam_xauth.so
```

I was mistaken about saying nothing under `/etc/pam.d`.  You'll want to check your `/etc/pam.d/su` file for starters; know there is also `su-l` and `sudo` and `sudo-i` in there at least in RHEL 7.9.

Comment: First paragraph. The `sudoers` file is nothing to do with `su`.

Comment: Yes, `sudoers` affects `sudo`, including when running `sudo command`, but it does not in any way affect `su`. You can `su` to root if you know root's password, no other group membership or anything else needed.

Comment: @terdon, i know for sure under a default RHEL 7.9 install from dvd if a user account is not in the wheel group then `su` will not allow that user to su to root.  When I posted above I was going from memory, looking now I believe it is `/etc/pam.d/su` that has `auth required pam_wheel.so use_uid` is what causes that; i was mistaken about it being in `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: Thanks, @ron, looks like I was mistaken too then! I didn't know red hat shipped with that Pam setting. If you remove that part about sudores I'll change my downvote to an upvote.